# How to deselect UITableViewCell after dismissing UIMenuController?

Tags: ios, uimenucontroller

I've implemented a long press gesture recognizer on a table view cell that shows the UIMenuController and when menu shows, the corresponding table view cell is getting selected which is my requirement.But the problem is when I touches out side,UIMenuController is getting dismissed but the cell is still in selected state.How to deselect the cell when pressing outside

Comment: where do you create UIMenuController?

Comment: How do you use to show UIMenuController, I Mean - UIPopOVerController

Answer (score 2):

I hope that, you are using the `UIPopOverController` to show the Menu .

Use the `Delegate` of **popoverControllerDidDismissPopover event** to get your solution

```
- (void) popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *) popoverController {
   [myTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:[myTable indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
}
```